# rename packagename and import class different

Tags: android

rename my package name and when import class Alt+Enter not import (import com.chalaksoft.tiptopapp.MusicPlayActivity) this way.
it import simple this:
com.chalaksoft.tiptopapp.MusicPlayActivity.set_text_comment(comment_count);

Comment: Wait what? `When import ... not import (import ...) ... it import` Can you explain better please?

Comment: not import in top of my code above class, it import in my code

Comment: check if any other import has done with class name `MusicPlayActivity`..if so, then remove it first and then try `Alt+Enter`..it'll do

Comment: no import with class name! when At+Enter not import in top it on my code

Comment: remove all import from top...and try again by pressing `Alt+Enter`